# I want to dynamically read columns and concatenate values by using in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I want to read columns dynamically and concatenate values by using in SSIS.  And it should generate a string of concatenate value which is **delaminated by '|'**.
Nunber of columns will be not constant.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

**Input**

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
123 ABC DEF
```

**Output**

```
Data
123|ABC|DEF
```

Could you please provide C# script for the same or any other solution.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Why don't you try writing the script yourself?   Which part of it are you stuck on, or unsure how to do?

Answer (score 0):

here is the script to retrieve the SQL Statement, note you need to convert the non-character/string columns to string type, then only the concatenation will work

```
DECLARE @tblName NVARCHAR(250), @SQLstmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLstmt = ''
SET @tblName = <Replace with your table name>
SELECT @SQLstmt = @SQLstmt + '|' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblName
SET @SQLstmt = SUBSTRING(@SQLstmt,2, LEN(@SQLstmt)-1)
```

PRINT @SQLstmt